# resizing image by mouse dragging using opencv python

Tags: python, opencv

I am new to python and computer vision programming. though I am trying to make an image resizing tool. for this purpose I am using python3.x and opencv2.
so far now I am able to resize an image by following code, its just an example.

```
my_img = cv2.imread('4.1.04.tiff')
resized_img = cv2.resize(my_img,None,fx=0.5, fy=0.5, interpolation = 
cv2.INTER_CUBIC)
cv2.imshow('Image',resized_img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Well, my problem is I dont know how to do resize an image by dragging mouse.
please let me know if it is possible in opencv or not and can be done using other libraries in python. Thanks!

Comment: You could use mouse wheel events instead. Pass its value to fx and fy in cv2.resize

Comment: @JeruLuke can you elaborate more on it, on mouse wheel event.
I tried to see what mouse wheel output gives. But didnt understand which value to pass!!!

Comment: @JeruLuke can you check my answer given below. I rewrote the code and used tracker bar instead of mouse event. Please kindly check my code there are some issues in it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I partially done the code for resizing image but its not working perfectly, there is some main window size problem occurring. If you re-run the code you will get it. I can not see full window and tracker bar too

```
import cv2
#import numpy as np

pro_img = None
a1 = 0.5 #for default size of image

def nothing(x):
    pass

def BnC_control(alpha):
    alpha = alpha/10
    #print(type(alpha))
    if alpha >= 0.1:
        return alpha
    else: 
        return 0.1


img = cv2.imread('watch.jpg')
#img = np.zeros((512,512,3),np.uint16)
cv2.namedWindow('Window1',cv2.WINDOW_AUTOSIZE)
cv2.createTrackbar('Alpha','Window1',1,10,nothing)



while(True):
    #r = BnC_control(a)
    #pro_img = cv2.resize(img,None,fx=0.3,fy=0.3)
    a = cv2.getTrackbarPos('Alpha','Window1')
    a1 = BnC_control(a)
    #print(a1)
    re_img = cv2.resize(img,None,fx=a1,fy=a1,interpolation = cv2.INTER_CUBIC)
    cv2.imshow('Window1',re_img)
    k = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
    if k == 27:
        break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Also when I change interpolation to INTER_AREA then it goes wrong..nothing happens and trackerbar gets disappear.

Comment: Inside the function `BnC_control()` replace the first line with `alpha = alpha/10.0`. It needs a `float` value to operate.

Comment: @JeruLuke Well thats working even without casting it to float. but why my window is resizing along with image. I mean only image is need to be resized. Isnt it?

Comment: Obviously, when your image resizes so does your window! Since you have mentioned `cv2.WINDOW_AUTOSIZE` it resizes the window to fit the image.

Comment: You have achieved what you wanted!

Comment: @JeruLuke yeah its working. But partially. main Window also resizing with image. Now I am trying to make canvas and display over it.

Comment: The window will adjust itself to the size of the image. So as long as the image is within the dimension of your screen the window will be of the same size. If you still think that I have not understood your problem could you elaborate it?

Comment: @JeruLuke yeah... you got my point but now what is need to be corrected? Is there any solution on it? Because I am trying to make canvas using Tkinter and displaying image on it.

Answer (score 0):

A simple code to show a trackbar used to resize the image. For more detail, see [this link](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.1/dc/d4d/tutorial_py_table_of_contents_gui.html).

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# method to be called by trackbar event
def onChange(pos):
    global img,dst,rows,cols

    # get value from trackbar
    value = cv2.getTrackbarPos("resize_trackbar", "Result")

    # resize image
    dst = cv2.resize(src=img, dsize=(cols+value,rows+value))

#Run Main
if __name__ == "__main__" :

    img = cv2.imread("image.jpg", -1)

    # get original image size
    rows,cols = img.shape[:2]

    # initialize dst image
    dst = np.copy(img)

    # create display window
    cv2.namedWindow("Result", cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)

    # create trackbar
    cv2.createTrackbar("resize_trackbar", "Result", 0, 50, onChange)

    while True:
        cv2.imshow("Result", dst)
        key = cv2.waitKey(1)
        if key == ord('q'):
            break

    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: I tried your code but its not working. Image is just flickering when I move tracker bar.

Comment: @NiranjanKulkarni Try it with a small image.

Comment: same thing is happening image is pixels are flickering now!!

Comment: Please check my revised code it is working but some window resize problem is occurring. I have posted my answer below.